# The set $c_{00} : = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : x_{n} =0 \ $ for almost all $ n \in \ \mathbb{N} \}$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

The set $c_{00} : = \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : x_{n} =0 \ $ for almost all $ n \in \ \mathbb{N} \}$ is compact on $X$ (where $X$ ist the set of all complex sequences).

$d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in X$

$d((x_n),(y_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1 + |x_n-y_n|}$

I know the two definitions of a compact set:

$i)$ In general,  is compact if every open cover of  contains a finite subcover of

$ii)$ In ,  is compact if it is closed and bounded.

My way of thinking is that I can choose for instance the following elements: $x_n = 0$ for almost all $n$ and I choose an exception let it be in every case from $n >=3$ if $n=3k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ then I will take $n$ the third power. Which means that $a_3=3, a_6=6^3, a_9= 9^3$ etc. In this case there is no upper bound so the sat is not compact. Is my way of thinking correct? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Which is the metric?

Comment: 1) Compactness depends on the topology. What is the topology on set of all complex sequences  ? Are you looking for this metric $d(z_n, w_n) =\sum_{n\in N} \frac{|z_n-w_n|}{1+|z_n-w_n|}$ ?                             2) Closed bounded and compactness are not equivalent in general.

Comment: $d:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $d((x_n),(y_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1 + |x_n-y_n|}$

Comment: Let $x^{(n)}_k=1$ for $k\le n$ and $x^{(n)}_k=0$ for $k>n$ and $x=(1,1,\ldots, 1,\ldots )$ we have $d(x^{(n)},x)\le 2^{-n}.$ As $x^{(n)}\in c_{00}$ and $x\notin c_{00}$ the set $c_{00}$  is not closed in $X,$ hence it is not compact.

Comment: Who told you that set was compact?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc This should be an official answer.

Comment: @PaulFrost OK. I will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_k^{(n)}=1$ for $k\le n$ and $x_k^{(n)}=0$ for $k>n.$ For $x=(1,1,\ldots, 1,\ldots )$ we have
$$d(x^{(n)},x)\le 2^{-n}$$
As $x^{(n)}\in c_{00}$ and $x\notin c_{00},$ the set $c_{00}$ is not closed in $X.$ Hence it is not compact.

**Remark** Since $d(x,y)\le 1$ for any $x,y\in X,$ the set $X$ is bounded.